# How to show a Count down Timer within and Alertbox in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

i have a Flutter app which should show a counting down timer in an alert box for Phone code confirming  (i need this timer to resend the code to my user when 60 second is up) , i start timer when i click on Confirm Button , but the problem is that the timer is not showing that he's going down he stills with a fixed value.

here is my alert box

[Alert Box with timer NOT SHOWING COUNT DOWN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9g2k.png)

here is my timer Function :

```
int _counter = 60;
   Timer _timer;
     void _startTimer(){
_counter = 60;
if(_timer != null){
  _timer.cancel();
}
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer){
  setState(() {
    (_counter > 0) ? _counter-- : _timer.cancel();
  });
});
}
```

here is my alert Box code :

```
void alertD(BuildContext ctx) {
var alert = AlertDialog(
    // title: Center(child:Text('Enter Code')),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
    elevation: 0.0,
    content: Container(
      height: 215,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 15),
              child: Text(
                'Enter Code',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green[800],
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16
                ),
              )),
          Container(
            height: 70,
            width: 180,
            child: TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 0.0)),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              maxLength: 10,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 1,
          ),
          Text('00:$_counter'),
          SizedBox(height: 15,)
          ,
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                child: Material(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(SignUpScreenSecond.routeName);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Colors.green,
                              Colors.grey,
                            ],
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Validate',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                child: Material(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Colors.grey,
                              Colors.green,
                            ],
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Resend',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ), //new column child
        ],
      ),
    ));
showDialog(
    context: ctx,
    builder: (BuildContext c) {
      return alert;
    });
 }
```

that's how i'm calling my alert dialog and my timer when i click Confirm Button :

```
onTap: () {
           _startTimer;
           alertD(context);
              },
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `StreamBuilder` and `StreamController` 
`AlertDialog` `content` continually receive `stream` `int` from `Timer`

code snippet

```
StreamController<int> _events;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = new StreamController<int>();
    _events.add(60);
  }

...
 _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      (_counter > 0) ? _counter-- : _timer.cancel();
      print(_counter);
      _events.add(_counter);
    });

...
content: StreamBuilder<int>(
            stream: _events.stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {

      ...
      Text('00:${snapshot.data.toString()}'),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  StreamController<int> _events;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = new StreamController<int>();
    _events.add(60);
  }

  Timer _timer;
  void _startTimer() {
    _counter = 60;
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      //setState(() {
      (_counter > 0) ? _counter-- : _timer.cancel();
      //});
      print(_counter);
      _events.add(_counter);
    });
  }

  void alertD(BuildContext ctx) {
    var alert = AlertDialog(
        // title: Center(child:Text('Enter Code')),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        elevation: 0.0,
        content: StreamBuilder<int>(
            stream: _events.stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.data.toString());
              return Container(
                height: 215,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 15),
                        child: Text(
                          'Enter Code',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green[800],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16),
                        )),
                    Container(
                      height: 70,
                      width: 180,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 0.0)),
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        maxLength: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1,
                    ),
                    Text('00:${snapshot.data.toString()}'),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          child: Material(
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                //Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(SignUpScreenSecond.routeName);
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [
                                        Colors.green,
                                        Colors.grey,
                                      ],
                                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                      end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                  'Validate',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                )),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          child: Material(
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [
                                        Colors.grey,
                                        Colors.green,
                                      ],
                                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                      end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                  'Resend',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                )),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ), //new column child
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }));
    showDialog(
        context: ctx,
        builder: (BuildContext c) {
          return alert;
        });
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _startTimer();
                  alertD(context);
                },
                child: Text('Click')),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me